# I tried using a handler, but it said 'cannot resolve symbol"Handler"'

Tags: java, android

What do i do to be able to use a handler to update my TextView every 2 secs because right now it comes up with 'cannot resolve symbol"Handler"'

```
int noStart = 20;
int minus = 5;

public void number(View view) {
    final TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);

    if(noStart<0){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                noStart -= minus;
                tx.setText(String.valueOf(noStart));
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: No thank you for telling me that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your activity imports and add this line to the class:

```
import android.os.*
```

Comment: Or import android.os.Handler if you want the specific namespace.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i refer to a constant of class Handler in outer calss, see as below:

```java
import static *.MyHandler.MSG_WHAT_PING_NETWORK;
public class OuterClass {
    // use MSG_WHAT_PING_NETWORK...
    // ...
}

class MyHandler extends Handler {
    public static final int MSG_WHAT_PING_NETWORK = 99;
    // ...
}
```

remove the import in outer class can solve the problem.